# Removing apostrophe in selected cell

Tags: vba, apostrophe

I'm a beginner in VBA.
Trying to change text values in my spreadsheet (example "'123" to "123") in selected area to General or Numeric.
I have my small code that able to select (but not changing to General)

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$49999").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="NUM"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$49999").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="0"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$49999").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>"

  With Selection
   .NumberFormat = "General"

    End With


End Sub
```

What should I change in the code to get required result?
Thanks for help!

Comment: You are trying to change row 1 into general. should it not be activesheet.Range("F:F").numberformat = "General";activesheet.Range("H:H").numberformat = "General";activesheet.Range("J:J").numberformat = "General"

Answer (score 0):

how did you get ' in your field?

In general, you can use:

> Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )

```
Dim LResult As String

LResult = Replace("alphabet", "a", "e")
```

In this example, the variable called LResult would now contain the value "elphebet".

Answer (score 0):

to convert Text to Number try this:

```
Sub ConvertTextNumberToNumber()
For Each WS In Sheets
On Error Resume Next
For Each r In WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = Val(r.Value)
Next
Next
End Sub
```

And you can call this function :

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$49999").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="NUM"
Call ConvertTextNumberToNumber()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$49999").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="0"
Call ConvertTextNumberToNumber()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$49999").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>"
Call ConvertTextNumberToNumber()


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Maximuuuuus.